# How to implement RecyclerView scrolling with Tooltip?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, tooltip

I have to implement `Tooltip` that is shown on top of `RecyclerView` elements and it should scroll vertically and horizontally.

Ideally I need to have `AdapterDelegates` which have horizontal and vertical `RecyclerView`s. By clicking on the inflated `View` of those `RecyclerView`s, `Tooltip` appears and it is not dismissed until clicking on the `View` again.

Though if I use `ScrollView` for vertical scrolling then `Tooltip` scrolls, but when I try to scroll horizontally in `RecyclerView` then `Tooltip` stays in the same spot (see GIF below)

I also tried to override `onInterceptTouchEvent` or to play with `onTouchListener`:

```java
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      dx = (int) (view.getX() - motionEvent.getRawX());
      dy = (int) (view.getY() - motionEvent.getRawY());
      return true;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      view.setX(motionEvent.getRawX() + dx);
      view.setY(motionEvent.getRawY() + dy);
      return true;
   }
return false;
```

But as example below shows then `Tooltip` consumes touch event and except `Tooltip` itself nothing moves:

[image: movable tooltip]

I tried many popular `Tooltip` libraries, but all of them didn't had the functionality I needed.

How can I achieve desired functionality?

Comment: consider using some [scrolling interface for `RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) and move your custom tooltip according to these changes